# Custom taxonomy and list of pages

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering how to add a list of existing pages to a custom taxonomy as terms.

My goal is to be able to add a reference to a page for an uploaded attachment.

I'm able to create the taxonomy and it shows up, it's just not populated.

Also - if there's a better way to go about this I'm all ears as well.

eg:
I have pages "Info","Contact"

I want these items to show up as terms.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to add these pages AS Categories (taxonomy terms) or do you want to assign existing pages to certain Categories you've created with your custom taxonomy?

Comment: The former. I'd like to be able to select a page that the attachment "belongs to".

Comment: Well you can hook into [Save Post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) and when a post is created you can [insert a term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) matching the page title. That doesn't necessarily mean the two are connected. Might I ask WHY you would like to do this? What's the purpose / how do you want it to function in the long run - maybe there's a better way to go about it.

Comment: We want to be able to tie attachments to specific pages without inserting them into the content. Example. We want a set of images in a carousel on a specific page. We would set the page, set some other tags or categories and then generate the carousel based on that. But we're using it for much more than just a carousel.

Comment: Sounds pretty custom and complex so I don't think this is a simple task... Is there not a carousel plugin you can use?

Comment: I'm not using it for just carousels. It's definitely custom. I think I'm headed down the right path though... I seem to be getting a list of pages currently. I'll post some code up in a minute.

Comment: Would it be better to use Post Meta to connect pages and attachments together?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by getting the pages and inserting them with `wp_insert_term`. Note: I only need a specific page so this is more specific than above.

```
// create a new taxonomy
function add_product_pages_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'productpages',
        'attachment',
        array(
            'hierarchical'=>true,
            'label' => __( 'Assign to Product Page' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'productpages' ),
            'show_in_nav_menus'=>false,

        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_product_pages_to_attachments' );

//populate the list
function populate_product_list()
{
    //get my specific page id which will be used in the 'parent' argument
    $id = get_page_by_path("products")->ID; 
    $args   = array(
        'post_type'=>'page',
        'parent'=>$id
    );
    //get all the pages matching the arguments above
    $pages = get_pages($args);
    //loop through the pages and add them to the taxonomy list
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        wp_insert_term($page->post_title,'productpages');
    }
    delete_option("productpages");
}
add_action('init','populate_product_list');
```